# Angular with Kendo, Using Grid Values Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, kendo-grid

Ok I'm pretty sure I know exactly what I need to do here but I'm not sure how to do it.  Basically I have a grid that I want to make a key column bind to an array of key/values, which I've done before with kendo (not using Angular) and I know that when I'm creating my key/value array asynchronously then that needs to complete before I can get them show-up with kendo, which I have done using promises before.

So here I have the same issue only angular is also involved.  I need to fetch and format an array of data into the format in which a kendo grid column can digest it, so no problem here is my controller code:

```
       var realm = kendo.data.Model.define({
            id: 'realmID',
            fields: {
                realmID: { editable: false, nullable: true }
                realmType: { type: 'string', validation: { required: true } }
            }
        })

        var ds1 = kendoHelpers.dataSourceFactory('realms', realm, 'realmID')

        var realmType = kendo.data.Model.define({
            id: 'realmTypeID',
            fields: {
                realmTypeID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                name: { type: 'string', validation: { required: true } }
            }
        })

        var ds2 = kendoHelpers.dataSourceFactory('realms/types', realmType, 'realmTypeID')

        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: ds1,
            editable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            autoBind:false,
            toolbar: [
                { name: "create" },
                { name: 'save' },
                { name: 'cancel' }
            ],
            columns: [
                { field: 'realmID', title: 'ID' }
                { field: 'realmTypeID', title: 'Realm Type', editor: realmTypesDDL, values: $scope.realmTypeValues },
                { command: "destroy" }
            ]
        }

        $scope.secondGridOptions = {
            dataSource: ds2,
            editable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            toolbar: [
                { name: "create" },
                { name: 'save' },
                { name: 'cancel' }
            ],
            columns: [
                { field: 'realmTypeID', title: 'ID' },
                { field: 'name', title: 'Name' }
                { command: "destroy" }
            ]
        }

        ds2.fetch(function () {
            $scope.realmTypeValues = [{ text: 'Test', value: "24bc2e62-f761-4e70-804c-bc36fdeced3d" }];
            //this.data().map(function (v, i) {
            //    $scope.realmTypeValues.push({ text: v.name, value: v.realmTypeID})
            //});
            //$scope.mainGridOptions.ds1.read()
        });


        function realmTypesDDL(container, options) {
            $('<input />')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    dataSource: ds2,
                    dataTextField: 'name',
                    dataValueField: 'realmTypeID'
                });
        }
```

I made this dataSourceFatory helper method above to return me a basic CRUD kendo dataSource that uses transport and also injects an authorization header which is working fine so don't get hung up on that, ultimately I'm going to be using this data in another grid as well as for reference values for the main grid, but I've hard coded some values that I can use to test with in the ds2.fetch callback.

My HTML is pretty plain:

```
<div>
    <h2>Realms</h2>
    <kendo-grid options="mainGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
    <h2>Realm Types</h2>
    <kendo-grid options="secondGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

This all works fine and well except I am only seeing the GUID of the realmTypeID in the grid, I click it and the editor is populated correctly so that's good but I want the text value to be displayed instead of the GUID.  I'm sure the issue is that the array of values is empty whenever angular is binding to the grid options.  My questions are:

1. **How do I either delay this bind operation or manually rebind it after the fetch call?**
2. **Is there a better way to handle a situation like this?  I try not to expend finite resources for no reason (IE making server calls when unnecessary)**

*Note:* When I move the creation of the text/value array to happen before the grid options, I get the desired behavior I am after

**EDIT** A work around is to not use the directive to create the grid and instead defer the grid creation until the callback of whatever data your column is dependent on, I was hoping for a more elegant solution but this is better than nothing.  So your HTML becomes something like

```
<h2>Realms</h2>
<div id="realms"></div>
<h2>Realm Types</h2>
<kendo-grid options="secondGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
```

Then you can create the grid in the fetch callback for example:

```
ds2.fetch(function () {this.data().map(function (v, i) {
        $scope.realmTypeValues.push({ text: v.name, value: v.realmTypeID})
    });
    $('#realms').kendoGrid($scope.mainGridOptions);
    $scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.fetch()
});
```

But this doesn't feel very angularish so I'm really hoping for a better solution!

Comment: Do you know that the read property of the transport object can also be a function? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud I use it to allow me to decide when to populate things.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, I don't see how that would help though?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...well I think I hacked this enough and without another suggestion I'm going to go forward with this approach.  I'm just going to move the binding logic to the requestEnd event of the second grid so that the values array can be populated right before the binding even.  I'm also reworking the values array in this method.  It is a bit weird though, I think there is some kendo black magic going on with this array because I can't just set it to a new empty array without it breaking completely...which is why I'm poping everything out prior to repopulating the array.  That way when something is deleted or edited in the second grid, the DDL in the first grid is updated in the callback.

```
        function requestEnd(e) {
        for (var i = $scope.realmTypeValues.length; i >= 0; i--) $scope.realmTypeValues.pop();

        var data;

        if (e.type == "read")
            data = e.response;
        else
            data = e.sender.data();

        data.map(function (v, i) { $scope.realmTypeValues.push({ text: v.name, value: v.realmTypeID }); });

        if ($('#realms').data('kendoGrid') == undefined) {
            $('#realms').kendoGrid($scope.mainGridOptions);
        }
        else
            $('#realms').data('kendoGrid').columns[4].values = $scope.realmTypeValues;
    }

    ds2.bind('requestEnd', requestEnd);
```

So I'm going to accept my own answer unless anyone has a better approach!